# React S3 Feature Branching

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I have my react app which is hosted on S3 as a static website, I would to setup based on feature branching for a test so there is the root S3 bucket folder and then a site or folder per feature i.e. `"/dev/profile-view"` or `"dev/new-ui"` however react has issues in finding the JS files and loading index if everything is not in the root folder if I set homepage in the package file it works but then when I deploy to production it does not. The page refresh is missed up as it can't find index.html

I spoke with AWS support and they said the following

Unfortunately, the S3 Website Feature currently configured on your Bucket `"au-boral-portal-development"` will not support a redirection behavior as you need for your case as like prepending a prefix `"/feature/*"` to all requests.

I spoke to our Developer Services Team and their advice was to address this use case via code, using baseURI parameter.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix this just adding PUBLIC_URL="."  in my .env.development file.